Controlling voltage of a device (Peltier cell) without PWM and with high current (max 5 V, 1 A)
I would like to be able to control the power of a Peltier cell, the TEC1-04901, (5 V, 1 A) in such a way as to control its temperature. I have already tried using a PWM control using a transistor first and then also with a motor driver and it works but it loses a lot in efficiency: if I try to give a value of 50%, for example, then the hot side gets very hot and the cold side after a short time becomes lukewarm again. On the other hand, if I try to give it 2.5 V stable (without PWM with an external voltage controlled power generator) then the cold side stays cold and stable for much longer as the hot side (without dissipation). My goal is to use the cell to reach temperatures close to room temperature, so I would hardly go above 50/60% power. I know about the existence of DACs and the microcontroller I am using (ESP32) would have two DAC pins but obviously they could not handle the power given to the cell (up to 1 A but for my uses maximum 400-600 mA). I would like to know if there is a way to provide, as with a DAC, a stable, analog and controlled voltage value to the cell instead of PWM using an external power supply, or still use PWM but "smooth" the signal so that the Pletier "see" a nice and clean wave. I tried to search online for a solution but I can't find anything that suits me.

Peltier coolers have miserable efficiency at the best of times, and to get even that you had best feed them with DC current (minimum ripple so the average and RMS currents are close to being equal).
One way to to use a high frequency PWM and use an L-C filter to smooth the current. This is essentially building a buck switching power supply. You can find plenty of information on buck regulators. From this TI app note on buck converter calculations:
You can replace the diode with a MOSFET to increase efficiency, but it's probably not worth worrying about at this point. SW will be a MOSFET in your case, controlled with a duty cycle D, so ideally Vout = Vin*D.
The higher the switching frequency the smaller the inductor L and the capacitor Cout can be, but the harder it is to get good efficiency in the switching transistor.

You could also just go out and buy a programmable DC power supply (for example, with a serial interface). This would allow you to set a current limit as well as controlling the voltage digitally with smooth transition from CC to CV control. This is just one example, be sure to shop around if you are thinking of making a purchase.

I have the 5A version similar to the one pictured (KA3005P) from Digikey and it has kind of a funky homemade DAC inside, but it does work acceptably well and has an RS-232 interface. I also have an LXI-programmed  Rigol triple one which is better designed and made, but is also much more expensive and I wouldn't want to dedicate it to one task.

Thanks a lot for the answer! I apologize for the question that might be ignorant, so the circuit needs capacitive and inductive elements, I wanted to know if cheaply there are any that can support the power required by the cell, because I know they can be found easily on Amazon or in Arduino kits but it seemed to me they were all for a few volts and amps
